# How to deregister script and style of a WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using a WordPress plugin called [WP-PostRatings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/). It autocratically include their script.js and style.css in Wp_head() and wp_footer(). It is fine but i only want to load these files on custom post type "tools", not on other post type.

Can i deregister these files on other post types and pages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (in your Theme functions.php):

```
if ( 'tools' != get_post_type() ) {
    remove_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ratings_scripts');
}
```

**Explanition:**
In the Plugin-File wp-postratings.php at line 140 you can see the CSS/JS injection. You can prevent this, if the posttype not match.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your theme function.php

```
function some_func( $query ){
        if ( is_post_type_archive('my_custom_post_type') ) {
              wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );//your script name
        }
    }
    add_action('pre_get_posts','some_func');
```